# How to convert a uint256 array to a bytes32 array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays, convert

Suppose I have a `uint256[]` array in Solidity. What's the easiest way to convert it to a `bytes32` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly is the easiest way:

```
function toBytes32(uint256[] memory arr_) internal pure returns (bytes32[] memory arr) {
    assembly {
        arr := arr_
    }
}
```

PRBMath uses this technique a lot, e.g. [here](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math/blob/a8009d7ac88a1c94fa57a09107eb3db06ef47744/test/utils/Assertions.sol#L296-L304).